# How to resize and change color of headlines in tableview xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a static Tableview on my storyboard 
that has headlines to the sections

[image]

The headlines text color and size is a static thing and I cannot change it
it results in very narrow headlines and black text.

how can I space out the headlines (make the height a bit bigger) and change the color of the text?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can i space out the headlines (make the height a bit bigger) and change the color of the text ?

You'll need to have a custom view that has a label, and return it to the delegate method of the `UITableView`'s `viewForHeaderInSection`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

**Ref:**

1. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-section-header-to-a-table-view
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614965-headerview

**EDIT:**

Here's how to achieve this. Basically you'll need a custom view in the delegate method I mentioned above. If you've successfully made a custom `UITableViewCell` in your `cellForRow` before, then this one should be a piece of cake for you.

You declare a container view, and then add your subviews in that container, in your case, a `UILabel`. I always use constraints, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // Let's make the even numbers sections a red background.
    // Blue background for odd numbers

    let container = UIView()
    container.backgroundColor = section % 2 == 0 ? .red : .blue

    let titleForHeaderLabel = UILabel()
    titleForHeaderLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    titleForHeaderLabel.text = "HEADER SECTION: \(section)"
    container.addSubview(titleForHeaderLabel)

    titleForHeaderLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    titleForHeaderLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    titleForHeaderLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
    titleForHeaderLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
    titleForHeaderLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

    return container
}
```

Then you provide a height for your section in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` delegate method, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 80.0
}
```

Output:

[image]

Easy, right? :) I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, let me try, since you've made this question open for bounty ;) :P